# Export masked data with mysqldump from a mariadb database

Tags: mysql, mariadb, data-masking

Some collegues asked me to extract certain data from a Mariadb db with mysqldump and to mask some of them due to their sensibility; so basically I should obtain a "masked" dump.
Is it possible to do this kind of thing?
I didn't find any clause to add to the command or tool to do it.
I just found this tool https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/sensitive-data-masking-with-mariadb-maxscale/ but at first glance, looks like I would be forced to mask data FOR EVERYONE and I can't do it because is a production db.
Any suggestion is absolutely welcome. :)

Comment: Create tables with the masked data and dumb them, after that delete them.

Comment: hehe it could be a solution but we're talking about a MASSIVE production db :) I don't think it could work.. Thank you anyway.

Comment: the size doesn't matter  as long there are only a few tables, and you can use CREATE TABLE xyz SELECT..., so that you need only one script it can rum at any time and it doesn't lock